# Magento 2: Show each time different comment depends on Field option value in system.xml

Tags: magento2, system-configuration, dependent-fields

Currently, using the below code in the `system.xml`

Does anyone have a more efficient way (using only one **Field** or some other way) to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="vendor" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Name of Module</label>
            <tab>tabname</tab>
            <resource>Namespace_ModuleName::method</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="connection" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Connection</label>
                <field id="ssl" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Check</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>                    
                </field>
                <field id="comment1" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <comment>If Yes Selected from Field ssl this comment should show.</comment>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="vendor/connection/ssl">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
                <field id="comment2" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <comment>If No Selected from Field ssl this comment should show.</comment>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="vendor/connection/ssl">0</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Using the above code(Separated Fields for each comment) seems to be working as different fields are involved.

Comment: I have done it , 5 mins please

Answer (score 2):

Answer: Working Solution

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="vendor" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Name of Module</label>
            <tab>tabname</tab>
            <resource>Namespace_ModuleName::method</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="connection" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Connection</label>
                <field id="ssl" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Check</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>                    
                    <comment>
                        <![CDATA[
                            <script>
                                require(['jquery'], function($){
                                    addExtremblerComment();
                                    $('#vendor_general_active').change(function(){
                                        $('#vendor_general_connection').parent('td').children('p').remove();
                                        addExtremblerComment();
                                    });
                                    function addExtremblerComment()
                                    {
                                        if($('#vendor_general_active').val() == true){
                                            $('#vendor_general_connection').after('<p class="note">If Yes Selected from Field ssl this comment should show.</p>');
                                        }
                                        if($('#vendor_general_active').val() == false){
                                            $('#vendor_general_connection').after('<p class="note">If No Selected from Field ssl this comment should show.</p>');
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            </script>
                        ]]>
                    </comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer